# The url requested was not found laravel 4

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel-4

I'm trying to create an app with laravel 4 but i'm facing a url issue. i have wamp installed on my machine. i set up a new virtual host in my httpd-vhost.conf with this code

```
<VirtualHost mobile.dev>  
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\mobile.dev\public"
ServerName mobile.dev

<Directory "C:\wamp\www\mobile.dev">
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AllowOverride All                  
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Deny from all
    Require all granted     
</Directory>
```

mobile.dev is a folder and also the domain name in my localhost.
here is my Route.php file

```
Route::get('/','HomeController@showWelcome');


Route::post('login','LoginController@userLogin');

Route::get('login','LoginController@getUsers');
```

when i ask for mobile.dev/login it gives me the requested url was not found.
can you help me please solve this issue. but when i ask for mobile.dev/ its working.

Here is my .htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Here is more details. when i remove my htaccess content everything works fine with the default url `http://mobile.dev/index.php/login` 
So the problem is in my htaccess and the rewriting in my virtual host

Comment: Show your Routes file

Comment: it's in the question `Route::get('/','HomeController@showWelcome');


Route::post('login','LoginController@userLogin()');

Route::get('login','LoginController@getUsers()');`

Comment: Why do you have parentheses after method names in your `routes.php`? More specifically, `LoginController@userLogin()`.

Comment: `Route::get('/'  ,'HomeController@showWelcome');
Route::post('login' ,'LoginController@userLogin');
Route::get('login' ,'LoginController@getUsers');` with this is not working

Comment: @Yazid Sorry, didn't see it :)

Answer (score 5):

It might be not Laravel problem, but seems your wamp server haven't enabled `mod_rewrite` in `httpd.conf` file yet. Locate the line -

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

and remove the comment symbol '#'. Then save the file and restart Apache.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem on a clean install of Apache Server on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Solution: 
1- when you have wamp installed in your machine please go to `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache*.*.*\conf\httpd.conf` and make sure that rewrite_mod is enabled by deleting the hash tag. (instead of using the interface provided by wamp)

2-there are two ways to enable rewriting for laravel in .htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

or using this :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

3- if you're setting a virtual host be sure to add this option in the `<virtualhost>` tag

```
 <Directory "C:\wamp\www\mobile.dev\public">
            Options FollowSymLinks Indexes Multiviews
            AllowOverride All  
   </Directory>
```

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
Route::post('login','LoginController@userLogin');
```

without the () after userLogin?

Comment: yeah i'm using it. it was just an error while writing the question.

Comment: Ok so when you go to mobile.dev you get the homepage of your website.
Do you have your controller file?

Answer (score 0):

Your `<Directory "C:\wamp\www\mobile.dev">` in config should be `<Directory "C:\wamp\www\mobile.dev\public">` to specify the public directory to the root of the htaccess rewrite rules.

I originally thought you were missing the `</IfModule>` at the end of your .htaccess file but when I posted my .htaccess file it hid the `</IfModule>` as well so that is a stack overflow issue. Otherwise your htaccess is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your response. i changed this option many time but with no success. i did it before asking.